# Save ggtern plots in R Shiny

Tags: r, plot, shiny, save, ggtern

What to add in server in order to save the plot as either png or svg?

Does ggsave work with ggtern? (which is an extension to ggplot for ternary plots)

Here is a minimal reproducible example of what I'm trying to do in Shiny:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggtern)
library(tidyverse)



ui <- fluidPage(

    downloadButton("dwnld", label = "Save plot"),
    plotOutput("ternary")
)


server <- function(input, output) {
    # ternary plot via ggtern
    output$ternary <- renderPlot({
        data <- tibble(x = 0.2, y = 0.3, z = 0.5)
        plot <- ggtern(data, aes(x = x, y = y, z = z)) + geom_point(size = 8)
        print(plot)
        
    })
    
    # download the plot
    #????????
}

 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: What is `plotInput`?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: My bad I will fix the code to make it reproducible. Thanks

Comment: I think `ggsave()` should just work.  I can't test this code because `shinyApp` just hangs for me (I don't know whether that's because you left something out or because I'm working in a funny environment (Emacs, not RStudio, development version of R, Linux ...) -- I don't do Shiny stuff very often.

Comment: @BenBolker that's strange, it's working on my machine. I've tried using `ggsave()` but it didn't work. I'm actually not sure what to put in the downloadHandler object on the server side.

Comment: well, let's hope someone more clueful comes along.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can proceed as follows:

```
myPlot <- reactive({
  data <- tibble(x = 0.2, y = 0.3, z = 0.5)
  ggtern(data, aes(x = x, y = y, z = z)) + geom_point(size = 8)
})

output[["ternary"]] <- renderPlot({
  myPlot()
})

output[["dwnld"]] <- downloadHandler(
  filename = "myPlot.png",
  content = function(file){
    ggsave(file, myPlot())
  }
)
```

Comment: Thank you!! This worked with the minimal example. However, it didn't work with my actual app. It's because I have the "data" object and ggtern inside the renderPlot and not in a separate reactive object. I am using a separate reactive objects for selecting the variables (x,y,z) from a csv file. Does ggtern has to be in a reactive expression?